# Facebook api android get friend list

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I achieved authentication between my android app and Facebook profile. I am able to get the logged in user data. However I require to get the users (only) playing the game (step 1).

This is my code so far:

```
 GraphRequest request =  new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/{user-id}/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {


                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Technically my response should be in JSON format, and I should be able to take from it what i need. However whenever i try that my project freezes and restarts.

For step2, do you have any suggestions on how to send the highest score from my application to post it on facebook, then be able to retrieve it and show it once i get the friend list playing the game?

Thank you

Comment: Re: step 2 - anything unclear about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements ...?

Comment: @CBroe for Step2 it became clear as i solved step 1. I still didn't work on it yet (just finished step1 with libgdx connection) but it should be simple i guess since the hard part is done.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using threads.

```
final GraphRequest request_getFriends = new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId() + "/friends?",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject();
                            try {
                                if (object !=null){
                                JSONArray data = object.getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                    String id = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                                    String name = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                                    ListOfFriendsIDS.add(id);
                                    ListOfFriendsNames.add(name);
                                }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
            );


            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    request_getFriends.executeAndWait();
                }
            }
            );

            t.start();
```

The code before was executing asynchronously there my result wasn't being fetched properly.

Answer (score -1):

Use this GameRequestDialog to load the friends who are non app users.

```
GameRequestDialog dialog;
GameRequestContent content = new 
GameRequestContent.Builder().
            setTitle("title").
            setMessage("message").
       setFilters(GameRequestContent.Filters.APP_NON_USERS) 
.build();
dialog.show(content);
```

Along with this, go through this it will provide a great help. It is the sample project of facebook implementations.

https://github.com/fbsamples/android-friend-smash

Hope that helps

Comment: I was able to do that using "/{user-id}/friends?" from the graph request and get the result in a JSON array.